# How to check whether the tomcat server is listening on particular port?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a servlet program with tomcat as server. But the tomcat server is not running. I looked at the services.msc but it's not there.
Below is the log created while running the servlet program via intelj

```
"E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2015-06-12 11:15:57,837] Artifact servlet:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Van\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_0_23_servlet"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.582 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.23.0
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.2
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_45-b15
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Van\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_0_23_servlet
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Van\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_0_23_servlet\conf\logging.properties
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\endorsed
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Vanuston\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Tomcat_8_0_23_servlet
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Avinash\Avinash\Inteljidea projects\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\temp
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.33 using APR version 1.5.1.
12-Jun-2015 11:15:59.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
12-Jun-2015 11:16:00.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015)
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.278 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.292 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.293 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2252 ms
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.348 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.349 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.355 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.362 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
12-Jun-2015 11:16:01.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 69 ms
Connected to server
[2015-06-12 11:16:01,503] Artifact servlet:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2015-06-12 11:16:02,178] Artifact servlet:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-06-12 11:16:02,178] Artifact servlet:war exploded: Deploy took 675 milliseconds
```

It actually opened the webpage but fails to print the message `hello world`. I think tomcat is not running on the specified port `8080`.

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Update:**

`localhost:8080/myservlet`  displays the `hello world` page but we need to enter the address manually. But upon running servlet project directly from intelj, it opens `localhost:8080` page which gives an empty page.

code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;
    private String mes;
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        // Do required initialization
        message = "Hello World.";
        mes = "Welcome to our new Page..";
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Actual logic goes here.
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1></br>" + "<h2>" + mes + "</h2>");
    }
    public void destroy()
    {
        // do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets do this. Download a new tomcat8 from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi. After, execute bin/startup.bat. And then try localhost:8080, you should see management app of tomcat. If you do not see we will look for root cause, if you see we will drill down to intellij.

Comment: If you think your app is deployed successfully, then you should be sharing your code (servlet or etc.), servlet mappings or similar to debug the problem.

Comment: @Rajesh but here, server is connected and my webapp is actually deployed.

Comment: If it is not working in the browser itself as you have mentioned in one of the answers then definitely it is a problem with your `tomcat` windows installation or any other service may be listening to that port `8080`. You could try a fresh installation though

Comment: @mustangDC is there any possiblity of port 8080 is used by another application. And i didn't installed tomcat. Just downloaded the tomcat.zip file and then i specify the path in the server configuration.

Comment: sorry, `http://localhost:8080/myservlet` works.. I failed to specify the path.. Thanks for your time.. I'm going to delete this question, i don't think that this will helpful to the future readers.

Comment: `wmic process list brief | find /i "tomcat.exe"` try this with Administrative priviledges. It will give you whether the process is used or not

Comment: @mustangDC see the above comment.

Comment: Obviously, `http://localhost:8080/myservlet` is the format you should use. :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Seems the application has deployed successfully. Try to access the application using the machine name and the port.

E.g.:- < pc-name >:8080

2. Else check in the tomcat server configuration connector details in;

   /conf/server.xml

In the server xml look for the connector details as below;

```
<Connector port="8080" address="localhost"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxPostSize="262144"
           maxThreads="250" minSpareThreads="25"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

There should be a connector which allows your browser listen to port 8080 and address to access the server.

Please try with above details.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `server.xml` file for Connector definition. That should tell you what port your server is listening on.

Another way to find out is using [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897437.aspx). This tool will list out the TCP ports for a given process.