# Pentaho Community Edition StartUp

Tags: pentaho

I downloaded Pentaho CE (Windows 10), unzipped, and ran start-pentaho.  Tomcat scripts run and end with a message "server startup in 31862 ms".   I checked Windows Task Manager, and indeed Tomcat is running. **However, how do I start Pentaho?**  I tried http://localhost:8080/pentaho but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you double check the correct port for the Pentaho Server? Have you tried using your ip instead of localhost?
[How to check tomcat port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796658/how-to-check-whether-the-tomcat-server-is-listening-on-particular-port)

However, are you sure Pentaho Server is the tool you are looking for?
If you are looking to do ETL, Data Integration,Data analysis etc... the tool you need is named Pentaho Data Integration

[PDI v8.3 Download Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho%208.3/client-tools/pdi-ce-8.3.0.0-371.zip/download)

If you are looking to do Reports the tool you need is named Pentaho Report designer
[Pentaho Report Designer Download Link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho%208.3/client-tools/prd-ce-8.3.0.0-371.zip/download)

Full list of client tool from Pentaho
[enter link description here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/)